# Predicting classes in Keras - IndexError: index 196 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 196

Tags: python, keras

I have trained a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) using Keras, and have saved the model to use it in predicting the class of some test images.

The input would be a combination of an image and the some numerical features (12 features in particular).

I have the following code for such test:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import optimizers
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

test_directory_edges = '/test'
test_df = pd.read_csv('/test.csv')
test_images_edge = []

df_test = pd.DataFrame(test_df)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
test_df = sc.fit_transform(test_df)
test_df = sc.transform(test_df)

test_border_irregularity_features = df_test.iloc[:,0:12].values

model = load_model('saved_model.h5')

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test_directory_edges):
    sortedFiles = sorted(files, key=lambda x:int(x.split('.')[0]))
    for file in sortedFiles[0:]:
        img = cv2.imread(root + '/' + file)
        img = cv2.resize(img,(512,512),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        img = img.reshape((-1,512,512,1))
        test_images_edge.append(img)

test_images_edge = np.array(test_images_edge)
test_images_edge = test_images_edge.reshape((-1,512,512,1))

#test_predictions = model.predict([test_images_edge,test_border_irregularity_features.reshape((196,12))])
test_predictions = model.predict([test_images_edge,test_border_irregularity_features])
# round predictions
test_rounded = [round(x[0]) for x in test_predictions]

test_prediction = pd.DataFrame(test_rounded,columns=['predictions']).to_csv('test_prediction.csv')
```

When I run the code however, I get the following:

```
IndexError: index 196 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 196
```

Which happens to be occurring on this line:

```
test_predictions = model.predict([test_images_edge,test_border_irregularity_features])
```

Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

Thanks.

**EDIT-1**

This is the *full stack trace*:

```
File "test_model.py", line 38, in <module>
    test_predictions = model.predict([test_images_edge,test_border_irregularity_features])
  File "/home/me/keras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1517, in predict
    batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
  File "/home/me/keras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1139, in _predict_loop
    ins_batch = _slice_arrays(ins, batch_ids)
  File "/home/me/keras/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 402, in _slice_arrays
    return [None if x is None else x[start] for x in arrays]
IndexError: index 196 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 196
```

This is the *model* code:

```
input_layer_edge = Conv2D(32,(5,5), activation='relu')(image_input_edge)
cov1_edge = Conv2D(24,(5,5),activation='relu',subsample=(2,2))(input_layer_edge)
cov2_edge = Conv2D(36,(5,5),activation='relu',subsample=(2,2))(cov1_edge)
cov3_edge = Conv2D(48,(5,5),activation='relu',subsample=(2,2))(cov2_edge)
cov4_edge = Conv2D(64,(5,5),activation='relu')(cov3_edge)
cov5_edge = Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu')(cov4_edge)
flatten_edge = Flatten()(cov5_edge)

merge = concatenate([flatten_edge,features_input])

d1 = Dense(100, activation='relu')(merge)
out = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(d1)

model = Model(inputs=[image_input_edge,features_input], outputs=[out])
```

Comment: Could you please include the full stack trace, as well as the model code? Is it the case that you are using an Embedding layer in your model?

Comment: @today Thanks for your kind reply. Yes, I have added those under **EDIT-1** in my question.

Comment: I am curious to know what the problem was, if you could find and resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to shape mismatch between input arrays. Specifically since your model has two input layers, the the two input arrays being fed to the model must have the same number of samples. Please verify this is the case by printing the shape of the two input arrays and check that the first number in both printed tuples are the same:

```
print(test_images_edge.shape, test_border_irregularity_features.shape)

# alternatively:
assert test_images_edge.shape[0] == test_border_irregularity_features.shape[0], "Different number of samples!"
```